# How to handle and send remote notifications Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, push-notification

I have some questions that i have been thinking of for a while. I hope to get them answered here.

1) I have many Push notifications sent to the device depending on whats happening on the device. Each push notification has its use for a different ViewController. In that way i mean that the push notification is being received with some custom data that a ViewController will need to use. 
So what is the best way to setup so it is easy to share the data from the notifications?

2) As i said earlier that i have different types of notifications. The way i have done now so i know what to do for each notification is that i send them like this:

```
data: {
       type: "4",
       some other data....
    }
```

So everytime a notification is received i have if statements to check what **type** it is. Is this a legit/correct way to do this or is there an other way?

I hope that you could provide some code examples especially for question 1.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` is where you will put your conditions.
the userInfo dictionary is where the info of the notification is stored.
for example to get the type you do it like so:

```
if([userInfo[@"aps"][@"type"] isEqualToString:@"4"])
{
    //your custom code here
}
```

Now when you receive a remote notification you'll want to send a local notification like so :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"yourMessage" object:nil];
```

then in your view controllers add:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourCustomMethod) name:@"yourMessage" object:nil];
```

don't forget to unregister for local notifications in your `viewWillDisappear:` method like so :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"yourMessage" object:nil];
```

Hope that helps, let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: It is pretty clear just some questions. I should put addObserver in ViewDidAppear or will appear right?. Also second question. Lets say i am in Viewcontroller A, And i receive a notification that where the type of that notification is to be used in ViewController B. Would it still get processed if i say set some property values for Viewcontroller B ?

Comment: You will have to put it in ViewWillAppear.
Since you are implementing removeObserver: only the current ViewController will get the local notification. So if you are in ViewController A and you receive a notification that is meant for ViewController B nothing will happen.
If you don't want this behaviour don't implement the removeObserver: method, but still ViewController B should be already initialised for it to be able to process the notification.

Comment: Is there a way to initialise it from viewController A from the start?

Comment: You can use the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method

Comment: Thank you, i will try to implement this!

Comment: Btw. I will have to send that instantiated instance when i push to the view controller right?

Comment: When pushing to a view controller with a segue it is being initialised so no need to to call instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier